# How to set height of scrollview according to the data programmatically using swift

Tags: swift, scrollview

I have a scroll view in which I have added multiple views one upon another where I am unable to set the height of the scroll view according to the data.

[image: Here is the screenshot of my screen]

I want to scroll my page until the save button.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: for that you need to good knowledge about `scrollview` & `constraints`.

Comment: Based on the screenshot I assume you are using UIKit and not SwiftUI. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I am using UIKit.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear about your question, from my understanding so far it looks like you might have a couple of possible options.

1. If you are trying to calculate data's height coming in you would do something similar to the line below and configure scrollView height equal to that label.

```swift
label.bounds.size.height
```

2. If you are looking to just push the 'save' button down the bottom of your scrollView regardless of the height of the scrollView. You might just be better off constraining the button to the bottom.

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    saveButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
    saveButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
    saveButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
    saveButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
])
```

3. If you are looking to fully control the height of the scrollView based on each view. I created a sample programmatic constraint file that manually adds the height constraints for each view.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    let scrollViewContainer: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .vertical
        view.spacing = 10
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 500).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    let blueView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    let greenView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1200).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // ** SWAP VIEWS FOR WHAT YOU NEED HERE **
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContainer)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(redView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(greenView)

        scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // THIS IS IMPORTANT FOR SCROLLING **LEAVE ALONE**
        scrollViewContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: 3rd point is exactly what i am needed but can't we do this using storyboard? Actually I have already created 5 view on scrollview in storyboard. And I have not implemented any stackview.

Comment: @RutuparnaPanda Yes you can still do this exact method in storyboard what you would need to do is set the constraint of the UIViews height and it would have the same effect!

Comment: I had set height to each view still it doesnot work.

Comment: Could you possibly chat with me about your project so I can take a look at it in more depth?